# What causes constant errors in ng test caused by changing tests or src files?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

`Ng test` seems to be incredibly unstable, i'm currently experimenting with tests and I'm constantly receiving nonsensical errors. Everything from supposedly missing modules to not being able to find methods and other utter rubbish that is instantly fixed by restarting `ng test`. Its worth noting that these errors tend to crash the tests so they don't run at all.

Example error:

```
Error: C:\Users\xxxx\Application\src\app\pages\login\login.component.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

These random errors seem to pop up when I am editing my test files or src files but are always fixed by restarting the ng test command. It's driving me crazy.

Is anyone else experiencing this and is there any fix?

Comment: Are you able to post the relevant `tsconfig.json` configuration you're using? Might help for an answer.

Comment: There's a few tsconfig files. I've edited my answer with the tsconfig.spec.json as i assume this is the relevant one.